# Remove horizontal line from last item in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have a map which loop all items in the products object and output each new items, What i want is to remove the red line under the "product 003", which is the last item.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t5fZ.png)

```
const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {products.map((product, index) => (
      <ShoppingList key={index} title={product.title} price={product.price} />
    ))}
  </View>
);
const ShoppingList = props => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.line}>
      <Text>{props.title}</Text>
      <Text>{props.price}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
const products = [
  {
    title: 'Product 001',
    price: '100000',
  },
  {
    title: 'Product 002',
    price: '20000',
  },
    {
    title: 'Product 003',
    price: '10000',
  },
];

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
  },
  line: {
    padding: 4,
    borderBottomColor: 'red',
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
  },
});
```

Comment: You can compare the length of the products to the last index of the product . Set a different style for the last index with condition. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the index provided in the `.map` loop

```
{products.map((product, index) => (
    (index === products.length) ? <ItemWithoutHorizontalLine /> : <ItemWithHorizontalLine />
))}
```

or use a [VirtualizedList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist#itemseparatorcomponent) (or any of the child components of VirtualizedList e.g., FlatList) and provide a ItemSeparatorComponent

```
<FlatList
     ...
     ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
</FlatList>
```